# returning just a key from a hash field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an ActivityPart model that has a field called activity_json. this field is a hash and has a key named "image". How do I select all "image" from the activity_json field? I did something like this but it didn't work:

```
x = ActivityPart.all.pluck(activity_json: ['image'])
```

my idea is to return all 'image' from the activiy_json field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

`ActivityPart.select("activity_json->'image' as image").map(&:image)`